# sending json object via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am creating a simple form input demo. Values are stored from a form in variables then they are put into json object and it is sent via ajax.

My Json object validates but how do I reference it in the data field in $.ajax? My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submitForm').on('click',function(event){
event.preventDefault();

    var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
    var lastName  = $('#lastName').val();
    var phone     = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    var address   = $('#address').val();
    var $out      = $("#formResults");

    $out.append("<p>" + firstName  +' '+ lastName + "</p>" +                                       
                "<p>" + $('#phoneNumber').val() + "</p>" + 

                    //json object
                     {
                       "firstName" : "firstName", 
                        "lastName" : "lastName",
                        "phoneNumber" : "phoneNumber",
                        "address" : "address"
                       }


                         $.ajax({
                         url: 'http://localhost/xyz/markup/',
                         method:  'GET',
                         data: jsonObject
                         error: alert("error")
                         complete: alert ("complete")
                                                 });
                                     });            
                                     });
```

thanks!

Comment: you have some commas missing: error: alert("error"),
                         complete: alert ("complete")...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"firstName" : "firstName",
```

should be

```
"firstName" : firstName,
              ^---     ^---note lack of quotes
```

and similarly for the other 3 fields.

you're trying to do `string:string`, instead of `string:variable`.

As well, nowhere in your code is `jsonObject` actually defined.

Major note: do not build JSON text yourself. It's very risky. One single syntax error (misplaced quote usually) and the whole json object becomes invalid. You'd be better off building a normal JS data structure, then using the provided json encoding facilities to produce the json string.

Comment: if i remove the quotes it will not validate in jsonlint. How come?

Comment: because you're producing something like `"firstname":John Doe` which is not valid json. like I said, don't try to build your own json string. Unless you know exactly what you're doing and what json's syntax requirements are, you'll just end up in trouble. have the JSON object do the encoding/stringfying for you.